# Multi hierarchical Level XML to Flat XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

i am new XSLT, can any body suggest exact XSLT code follwing tranformation:::
Multi hierarchical XML File is Below ::

```
<ROOT>
    <RECORD>
        <TAG1> One </TAG1>
        <TAG2> Two A</TAG2>
        <TAG2> Two B</TAG2>
        <TAG3> Three</TAG3>
        <TAG4> Four A</TAG4>
        <TAG4> Four B</TAG4>
        <TAG5> Five </TAG5>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <TAG1> One </TAG1>
        <TAG2> Two A</TAG2>
        <TAG2> Two B</TAG2>
        <TAG2> Two C</TAG2>
        <TAG3> Three</TAG3>
        <TAG4> Four A</TAG4>
        <TAG4> Four B</TAG4>
        <TAG4> Four C</TAG4>
        <TAG5> Five </TAG5>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <TAG1> One </TAG1>
        <TAG2> Two</TAG2>
        <TAG3> Three</TAG3>
        <TAG4> Four</TAG4>
        <TAG5> Five </TAG5>
    </RECORD>
</ROOT>
```

I wnat to convert above to as following::

```
<ROOT>
    <RECORD>
        <TAG1> One </TAG1>
        <TAG2> Two A</TAG2>
        <TAG3> Three</TAG3>
        <TAG4> Four A</TAG4>
        <TAG5> Five </TAG5>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <TAG1> One </TAG1>      
        <TAG2> Two B</TAG2>
        <TAG3> Three</TAG3>     
        <TAG4> Four B</TAG4>
        <TAG5> Five </TAG5>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <TAG1> One </TAG1>
        <TAG2> Two A</TAG2>
        <TAG3> Three</TAG3>
        <TAG4> Four A</TAG4>
        <TAG5> Five </TAG5>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <TAG1> One </TAG1>
        <TAG2> Two B</TAG2>
        <TAG3> Three</TAG3>
        <TAG4> Four B</TAG4>
        <TAG5> Five </TAG5>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <TAG1> One </TAG1>
        <TAG2> Two C</TAG2>
        <TAG3> Three</TAG3>
        <TAG4> Four C</TAG4>
        <TAG5> Five </TAG5>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
        <TAG1> One </TAG1>
        <TAG2> Two</TAG2>
        <TAG3> Three</TAG3>
        <TAG4> Four</TAG4>
        <TAG5> Five </TAG5>
    </RECORD>
</ROOT>
```

Can any body suggest XSLT code for this ??
Thanks.

Comment: It is not at all clear what rules you are using in your transformation. How do you determine the output format from the input?

Comment: Tahks for quick reply, in above XML we have multi values for some tags like <TAG2> and <TAG4>. i want to split that multi(<TAG2>, <TAG4>) tags into different <RECORD> tag with remainn(<TAG1>, <TAG3>, <TAG5>) tag values. Thanks

Comment: Is the same number of TAG2 as the number of TAG4 in each record? TAG2 & TAG4 are the only multi values tag?

Comment: @Erlock Yes same number of tags.

Comment: In the "wanted result" the combination "two A", "four A" occurs twice. Is this an error and if not, could you, please, explain the rules for producing the combinations? For example, can there be a combination of the type: "two A", "four B" ?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Yes, Mapping is like this, 1st value in <TAG2> and 1st value in <TAG4> next, 2nd value in <TAG2> and 2nd value in <TAG4> and so on.

Comment: @ram.bi: Please, edit the question and explain legibly and unambiguously. Right now it is confusing and there aren't any rules -- one needs to guess and the result of guessing may not be what you intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, a named template (function) is mandatory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="addRecord">
        <xsl:param name="rank" select="1" />
        <xsl:param name="numberOfRecords" />
        <xsl:if test="$rank &lt;= $numberOfRecords">
            <RECORD>
                <xsl:copy-of select="TAG1" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="TAG2[$rank]" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="TAG3" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="TAG4[$rank]" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="TAG5" />
            </RECORD>
            <xsl:call-template name="addRecord">
                <xsl:with-param name="rank" select="$rank + 1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="numberOfRecords" select="$numberOfRecords" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ROOT">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="RECORD" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="RECORD">
        <xsl:call-template name="addRecord">
            <xsl:with-param name="numberOfRecords">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(TAG2) &gt; count(TAG4)">
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(TAG2)" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(TAG4)" />                   
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: So don't forget to tag your question as answered. :)

Comment: One more doubt, if the number of <TAG2> and <TAG4> are not equal then how can i achive that ??